# How to pass a value from function in aspx to cs.file

Tags: c#, javascript, html, html.dropdownlistfor

I am sure that I am missing a small thing. I have ddl and a function, i want to pass the 'value attribute' of a chosen ddl option to my function in cs file.
But I cant get the value attribute..
-I checked the DDL and the Value attribute is fine and helds my info well.
--I tried using the word - **this.**  to get my value but it didnt work..
 aspx page

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="myDdl" runat="server"  onchange='<%# orgenaize('here I need the value attribute') %>'/><br />
```

aspx.cs file

```
 public void orgenaizeCheckBox(string currentId)
        {
             //do something
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add javascript event handler using Attributes.Add in code behind where you can easily use the value from dll.

```
myDdl.Attributes.Add("onchange", "orgenaize(" + dllClass.Attribute + ");");
```

Comment: Ok,  in the ddl tag should i change something?

Comment: Remove the onchange event from the DropDownList tag

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp: DropDownList ID ="ddlValue" runat ="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlValue_SelectedIndexChanged"
ToolTip ="Please Select value">
</asp: DropDownList>
```

Then in your .cs class just handle the event

```
protected void ddlPhoneModel_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 // What ever you want to do on selected index change
  ddlValue.SelectedItem.Value
}
```

.Value should work, long time since i played around with Web controls but that should work